# systemct1 status plymouth-start.service

Tags: boot, hard-drive, plymouth

Alright so I am having a laptop issue & my one is in the shop getting on 7 weeks now, so a couple weeks back I bought a cheap one from a pawnbrokers & that crashed after the first update that it attempted. So I have an old pen drive w/a copy of Ubuntu 15.04 from years ago that I tried to install, so I could have a functioning laptop. Anyway that did not work & I kinda sussed that was due to a faulty hard drive so I got a new one for cheap & plugged that in. For this new hard drive I am too cheap to want to buy the windows key, especially for a laptop that's cheap & old, so I am back to trying to install Linux.

So I trialled it & immediately run into an issue w/a password that isn't set up because this is the first time the laptop is starting w/a fresh hard disk. So whatever, I reboot it & try again to install it. Now I am running into the issue of it failing to install because

> systemct1 status plymouth-start.service

So I looked into the Plymouth start service & why I might be having this problem. Apparently it is the function responsible for starting up and shutting down Linux. Apparently a reason I might be having this is another OS on this computer that hasn't shut down correctly.

I am not sure what to make of this, does anyone have an answer for me?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 15.04 was the 2015-April release of Ubuntu, and reached EOL back in 2016, and thus is off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  (FYI:  I'd check your details; 2015 was a long time ago, but I don't recall 15.04 using systemd)

Comment: @guiverc I'm aware, but w/out a laptop w/a functioning OS I do not think I have the capacity to attempt an install of a more recent distro, unless you can direct me to somewhere where my question would be relevant, then these are the cards in my hand.   Also if you think that the commands look wrong, I promise you I am just reporting the messages that are on my screen

Comment: Read the link I provided in my first comment; it will refer you to SE *Unix & Linux*.